# Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar constraints layout Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

This was my first time using Android studio and I don't know what are those errors mean and i saw many solution include change appcomat to alpha1 and change theme into base.theme and many but no one is working

Render Problem
    "Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme   Tip: Try to refresh the layout. "

Gradle Scripts>build.gradle

> dependencies {
>       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
>       implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
>       implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
>       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
>       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
>   }
>
> res>values>style.xml
>         style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
>           
>           @color/colorPrimary
>           @color/colorPrimaryDark
>           @color/colorAccent

[image]
Image 1

[image]
Image 2

Comment: try to add this in you xml style `<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout</item>`

Answer (score 1):

**Open Your build.gradle(Module: app)**

**Write**

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

**instead of**

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'

***Hope it will Help You***

Answer (score 0):

**These are my dependenceis en it works fine for me**

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Hope it will work.